# Table row is resizing when adding filter script class?

Tags: css, filter, html-table, width

I need to filter table rows by category so class `filterTr` is added to element `<tr>` but then element `<tr>` resizes in width and no longer aligns with element `<th>` above.

I don't know why this happens. The snippet below is a simplified version but the same thing happens here:

```js
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterTr");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("sowClndr-filter");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
/* Table filter */
.filterTr {
  display: none;
}
.filterBtn {
    margin-top:-10px!important;
    background-color:rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
    border:1px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00)!important;
    text-align:left!important;
    font-weight:400!important;
    text-overflow:ellipsis!important;
    white-space:nowrap!important;
    overflow:hidden!important;
}
.filterBtn:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00)!important;
    color:rgba(0,145,255,1.00)!important;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,145,255,1.00)!important;
}
.btn.active {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.00)!important;
    color:rgba(0,145,255,1.00)!important;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,145,255,1.00)!important;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Table styles */
.sowClndr-tr {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00)!important;
    border:0!important;
}
.sowClndr-tr:hover {
    background-color:rgba(55,175,75,0.15)!important;
    border:0!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="sowClndr-filter">
          <button class="btn btn-primary filterBtn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> All selections</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary filterBtn" onclick="filterSelection('A')"> selection A</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary filterBtn" onclick="filterSelection('B')"> selection B</button>
        </div>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sowClndr-tr filterTr A">
    <td>S1 fname lname</td>
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sowClndr-tr filterTr B">
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The CSS style `display:block;` for class `.show` messes up the table layout because class `.show` is added to `<tr>` using JS to make it visible. The solution is to use CSS style `display:table-row;` instead, now it works. I did not know that this style existed untill now.